# How hive access Hadoop setup using different user

Tags: hadoop, hive

If i install hadoop using 'hadoop' user, and install hive using 'hive' user on same node(Pseudo distribution mode).

How can my hive access hadoop?

when i input 'hive --version', i receive error like this:
Cannot find hadoop installation: $HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path.

The question is hive user have no right to access hadoop, but i don't know how to fix it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The system users of hadoop ecosystem like hdfs, hadoop, hive have access on the required services as part of installation that is taken care. But what do you mean that you installed hadoop using hadoop user, you should use service principal to do it who has admin rights.

Comment: In many documents, they said create a normal user 'hadoop', then unzip hadoop and run it. So i installed hadoop not using root. I am not sure what i do is right.

Comment: Those steps are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, `$HADOOP_HOME or $HADOOP_PREFIX must be set or hadoop must be in the path`.

So, edit `/home/hive/.bash_profile`, for example assuming you're on Linux, and add one of those values to set the environment variable to the downloaded Hadoop package

For example

```bash
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop  # example 
export PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: maybe i get the point. I installed hadoop in /home/hadoop/hadoop10, so the hive user cannot access the directory. Maybe i should install hadoop in /opt.

Comment: Right. One suggestion would be to use `groupadd` command to create a Unix group, then move the Hadoop package under /opt, then use `useradd`/`usermod` to create/insert at least an hdfs, zookeeper, and hive Unix user in that group... Then `chown -R root:hadoop /opt/hadoop` and `chmod -R 770 /opt/hadoop`.

Comment: Also "hadoop10"? You should be installing Hadoop 3.x, not 1.0, based on latest Apache Hadoop official documentation